# apt-get time out on docker-container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, quorum

**General information:**
I have a docker container running on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.
The Container itself runs on ubuntu aswell.
I’m behind a corporate proxy.

**Problem:**
When I try to run “apt-get update” I get a “connection timed out” error every time.
When I try to ping a ip, it just gets stuck and doesnt respond.

**What I tried:**

edited the /etc/default/docker for DNS and proxy
edited /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf
I have full internet-access on my host maschine. When I run apt-get update or any other command on the docker container, it recognizes the ip of the service but then just times out.

**==>** Running the quorum-maker on AWS EC2 Maschine (https://github.com/synechron-finlabs/quorum-maker#setting-up-quorum-network-on-multiple-machines)

Answer (score 0):

You must define the proxy inside the image. This is usually done while creating the image on the Dockerfile

`# Define environment variable
ENV http_proxy=http://my_username:my_password@my_host:port
ENV https_proxy=https://my_username:my_password@my_host:port`

Not sure how must this be done in an image on AWS... but probably you can set up the environment vars inside the container using export and that should be enough, but that will do it only for that session. If possible rearrange the image (building it again) setting up the proxy environment vars.

Comment: Hey thanks for your fast help! The image I'm using is prebuild from the GitHub repository...
I ll try to change the env vars inside the container and then docker commit

Comment: I tried to set the env vars with "export", now I'm getting "could not resolve <proxy>"

Comment: Try setting up the env vars but leave all the dns as is by default... so undo what you did on dns.

Comment: Changed the DNS setting in the /etc/default/docker back to default, restarted docker and started a new container, did

export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:8080

export https_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:8080

still the same error: could not resolve 'proxy'...

Comment: Quite strange... it should work. Do you have opportunity to build the image using github's Dockerfile? Try to build it setting up the env vars.

Comment: So I set up two files(http-proxy.conf and https-proxy.conf) in /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d of the host maschine. When I go "apt-get install nano" for example, I get :
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  spell
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nano
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 191 kB of archives.
After this operation, 700 kB of additional disk space will be used.
and after that it gets stuck. So obviously it gets all the information

Comment: but then gets stuck

Comment: What if no proxy used? And outside the container everything works fine with connection by http/https?